# about flash and XML

Tags: flash-cs3

How can i combine the fla file and xml file into single swf file.. ???

Answer (score 0):

make a new xml data file in the flash itself, for example:

```
var xml:XML = new XML("<startnode><secondnode>something</secondnode></startnode>");
```

the most successful way ive used this is to create a holder file for it with a static var containing the xml information for import.